# Need a VBA to count the number of entries in each sheet and list it in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. I want to count the number of entries  from column A from each sheet and list them in a final sheet. For example,

Sheet 1 has 30 entries
Sheet 2 has 40 entries
Sheet 3 for listing the number of entries

I am looking for an output in A1 and B1 as:

Sheet 1 30
Sheet 2 40

One of the major challenges is that the number of sheets are not defined. Few of the times it may also reach to 4 to 5 sheets. Can we build a user defined number of sheets to be considered and then run the count command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRowWS As Long, LastRowRS As Long

    'Loop all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Do not count if sheet name is Results. This sheets has the counts
        With ws
            If .Name <> "Results" Then
                'Find last row of worksheet ws column A
                LastRowWS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
                    'Find last row of worksheet Results column A
                    LastRowRS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    'Add the results
                    .Range("A" & LastRowRS + 1).Value = ws.Name
                    .Range("B" & LastRowRS + 1).Value = LastRowWS
                End With

            End If

        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Note**

Column A of each sheet does not have headers.

**Sheets Column A**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank  you so much. :)

Comment: Hi ,  I have used the above code, but it counts even blank entries any way to ignore blank entries in columns and count only available entries.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTA function counts all entries in a range. A range can be a column. So

```
   =CountA(A:A)  returns the number of entries in column A
```

You can add the sheet name to refer to a range in a different sheet

```
  =CountA(sheet2!A:A)  counts all the entries in column A in sheet2
```